# dynamically assigns memory in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically Growing an Array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903169/dynamically-growing-an-array-in-c)

I want to create a loop (do while) and create there until a specidfic case(while) objects of a class. 
Is it possible not to define the number of the objects(for example in an array of objects). I thought to store them in a txt. However is there alternative just with the use of memory??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261440/dynamic-allocation-of-memory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717199/dynamically-created-arrays and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903169/dynamically-growing-an-array-in-c and so many others.

Comment: Look up `std::vector<>`.  It's the easiest way to store a variable number of objects.

Comment: If you want to store them in a text file during the loop iteration, you could just stick with temporary objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use std::vector<> and you don't need to handle the allocation at all. Just iterate and add to the vector when you need to. It will grow dynamically to accommodate its contents.